# Compare Sonarqube Branch against Trunk Issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

We used SonarQube Version 5.0 for our Quality analysis. After the the server version upgrade to 5.4, wen can't find the option to compare the branch against a trunk. The documentation is not very clear in this point.

Can you help me?

Comment: Which feature are you talking about ? Is it a feature that were existing in 5.0 ?

Comment: Yeah right, this feature exists in 5.0, but we cant find it in 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for the **Compare Projects** feature, look under the **More** menu item.